# Error and problems after publishing ASP.NET 5 vNext RC2 to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

When I publish to Azure my tiny, tiny test project, configured in the latest vNext RC2, I get the following error upon first load after an extremely long wait:

```
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.
```

Subsequently if the app is anything more than the very simple "Hello World" project below, i.e. it uses some MVC etc. then the app is extremely unresponsive, failing to load some images, taking minutes to load each page. Although sometimes it's suddenly fast for a little while, then slow again.

In RC2 there were [some changes to the hosting setup](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/131), but all these have been implemented in my tiny test project.

I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695057/asp-net-5-vnext-causing-a-500-internal-server-error-on-azure) and ensured I am publishing the exact correct version of the CLR, in fact for information the same result happens if I use full or core CLR.

Here is the example project (publishing profiles removed):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpkrj6c74eaytjz/TinyProject.zip?dl=1

If I create a new RC1 project, the problem doesn't surface, but as soon as I update it to RC2 the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I solved this by creating an App Service Plan that was anything other than the free or shared option, in my case B1 (screenshot from Visual Studio Azure SDK):

[image]

Comment: I just had to do this as well... not sure why it fixed my issues. Also on the Free plan it took so long for the application to startup (a minimal barebones aspnet core rc2 application took too long to startup)

Answer (score 0):

Has your Azure Web app instance had a RC1 instance uploaded to it prior to your RC2? Your project looks ok to me, I can't see anything wrong at first glimpse with your project.json, Startup.cs or hosting.json files. I had an instance of RC1 on a Web App, and when trying to upload RC2, nothing would work, just a long long wait until eventually it would time out with a 503 error. I deleted the Web App, and just published the RC2 (using same DNX build as yourself) and everything works fine (so far!).

Also, if you turn on Diagnostic logging in your Web App, does that provide any more info?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what region were you using?

Comment: Also, sorry, yes I've tried a brand new web app instance, with no prior RC1 and no luck :(

Comment: Also, which DNX build exactly are you using?

Comment: I'm using the West Europe region, and using dnx 1.0.0-rc2-16357 which I believe is the same version you're trying to use? Is it just a free web app instance you're using to test on? I know the Free and Shared modes will have limited resources - they also go idle after a period of inactivity and bringing it back up will take ~30 secs when browsing to its URL, but if you've had success with RC1 it's unlikely to be the cause. Which region are you using?

Comment: Also, how are you uploading your app to Azure? Just through VS Web Publish? If so, have you made sure you've specified the right DNX version when you're publishing?

Comment: Funny you say that about free and shared, I managed to get it working about half an hour ago by trying with the lowest non free or shared option, B1. I was just doing a few more tests before posting my answer :) thanks for your help